# How do I implement a "Settings" section for a custom Teams Message Extension?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I built a small teams message extension which just uses some user input, builds a link from it, and returns a card with a button pointing to that link.

I need to add a ***Settings*** section, but I couldn't find proper instructions or a sample for this.
I tried to use [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/901bc140f5aa300fbfa852e64afd7c65fceebff9/samples/javascript_nodejs/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config) as example (which is JS, and I'm using TypeScript), but I could not get it to work.

Relevant portion in my class:

```
export class MessageExtensionBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
  
  ...

  protected handleTeamsMessagingExtensionConfigurationQuerySettingUrl(context: TurnContext, query: MessagingExtensionQuery): Promise<MessagingExtensionResponse> {
        return Promise.resolve({
            composeExtension: {
                type: "config",
                suggestedActions: {
                    actions: [
                        {
                            title: "Title",
                            type: ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                            value: "https://" + `${process.env.PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}` + "/settings.html"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        });
    }

  protected handleTeamsMessagingExtensionConfigurationSetting(context, settings): Promise<void> {
        return Promise.resolve(undefined);
    }
```

`process.env.PUBLIC_HOSTNAME` points to the temporary ngrok link, smth like *xxx-yyy-zzz.ngrok.io*.

When I access *xxx-yyy-zzz.ngrok.io/settings.html*, I get the correct content of that *html* file

I also added `"canUpdateConfiguration": true,` in my manifest file, and the *Settings* link is available.

**THE PROBLEM**: when I click the *Settings* link in my custom teams message extension, all I get is a pop-up with the error message `Sorry, the setting of this compose extension is not available. Please try again later.` and an `OK` button.

***What is wrong/missing in my code ?***

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have added Microsoft Teams(Channels) in Azure bot?

Comment: Yes, that I did. My message extension app worked, it was just the "settings" section which I could not get to work.

Answer (score 1):

We also faced this issue. It is resolved after adding validDomains in the manifest. Please try updating the validDomains in manifest, hope this resolves the issue.